# Woocommerce Square not accepting payment when Customer choose Saved card

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, square

We are using woocommerce and setup square account with it. All things are working fine but when customer choose his saved card, it did not accept that one.

After checking the console it send verification ajax and that return something error.

Error like this. : {"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"NOT_FOUND","detail":"Resource not found.","field":"payment_source"}]}

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Everything up to date?

Comment: Yes all up to date on website. it works for new card and other payments but when we use saved card then that ajax failed. @ngearing

Comment: Have you checked the Woo/square logs? And then check square account to see if transaction came through but failed for some reason. After that contact plugin developer or Square directly for solution.